# Show new values from a selected button

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropdown

I am facing a problem here. The purpose of the application is:

When selecting the "Categoria do carro" (car category), enable the next filter "Largura" (Width) with options predefined by Javascript. The "Largura" filter options will change depending on the category you choose.

Example: The "Passeio" category shows in the Largura filter the options: 500, 505, 510, 515. If the person selects the "Suv / Pickup" category, then the Largura filter will show the sizes 400, 410  and so it will, since in the end will have 4 filters, each dependent on the previous. I just need a light to get started

So the Largura filter will only have some content (which will be the buttons I left out of sample) when I selected the car category

example: https://codepen.io/KaioRocha/pen/PoYZePr

I tryed to make it work with input select, but I couldn't customize the filter so much like that

html

```
    <div class="filters">
<div class="container" style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between">
        <div class="ui-group">
            <span>Categoria</span>
            <div class="selecionar" onclick="abrirFiltroCategoria()">
                <p class="valueCategoria">Selecionar categoria</p>
            </div>
            <div class="button-group js-radio-button-group box__categoria" data-filter-group="color" >
                <button id="categoria_carro" class="button" data-filter=".red" value="Passeio" onclick="mostrarValueCategoria(this)">Passeio</button>
                <button class="button" data-filter=".blue" value="SUV/Pickup/4x4" onclick="mostrarValueCategoria(this)">SUV/Pickup/4x4</button>
                <button class="button" data-filter=".yellow" value="Van e Utilitário" onclick="mostrarValueCategoria(this)">Van e Utilitário</button>
                <button class="button" data-filter=".yellow" value="Caminhão e Carga" onclick="mostrarValueCategoria(this)">Caminhão e Carga</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="ui-group">
            <span>Largura</span>
            <div class="selecionar" onclick="abrirFiltroLargura()">
                <p class="valueLargura">Selecionar largura</p>
            </div>
            <div class="button-group js-radio-button-group box__largura" data-filter-group="size" id="largura_carro">
                <button class="button is-checked" data-filter="" value="500" onclick="mostrarValueLargura(this)">500</button>
                <button class="button" data-filter=".small" value="505" onclick="mostrarValueLargura(this)">505</button>
                <button class="button" data-filter=".wide" value="510" onclick="mostrarValueLargura(this)">510</button>
                <button class="button" data-filter=".big" value="515" onclick="mostrarValueLargura(this)">515</button>
            </div>
        </div>        
    </div>
```

js

````
    // open Box Categoria
    function abrirFiltroCategoria() {
        var x = document.querySelector(".box__categoria");
        if (x.style.display == 'none' || x.style.display == '') {
            x.style.display = "flex";
        } else {
            x.style.display = "none";
        }
    }

    // open Box Largura
    function abrirFiltroLargura(){
        var x = document.querySelector(".box__largura");
        if (x.style.display == 'none' || x.style.display == '') {
            x.style.display = "flex";
        } else {
            x.style.display = "none";
        }
    }


    // get value from categoria and show
    function mostrarValueCategoria(el) {
        document.querySelector('.valueCategoria').innerText = el.value;
    }

    // get value from largura  and show
    function mostrarValueLargura(el) {
        document.querySelector('.valueLargura').innerHTML = el.value;
    }

```
````

Comment: Don't understand the problem, you have just the "Passeio" category numbers, each category should have its own "largura" options.

Comment: So the content in the Largura filter is just an example. For each Category, the Largura content will be changed.

Like,
Category "Passerio" has the "Largura": 500,510,515,
Category "SUV" has the "Largura": 400,410,415

However, I need to get these values, these numbers by Javascript to be dynamic. The filter content I left was just for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through all the children buttons of `largura_carro` :

```
$('#largura_carro').children('button').each(function(i) {
  $(this).val(larguraValue[i]);
});
```

asuming you have an array called `larguraValue` with all the values of the buttons `[405,410,430,450]` for example.

Comment: yes you can have all the values in the JS code and then in `mostrarValueCategoria` you can do `larguraValue = largurasSUV ` or whatever category was selected.

Comment: Nice! I'll try it